# Birt Dynamic List Parameter Remains Empty

Tags: list, dynamic, parameters, birt

I have a Birt report with a dynamic list parameter. However the dynamic list always remains empty. It will never fill in the values. I know that the Dynamic List query is ok because if I place them in a table on the report itself it shows the correct data. The list parameter is never filled however. I have tried it with a combo box and a list, I have tried adding a default value but nothing works. I do notice it adds a blank option however. Any insight? Should I put in a bug report?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Since I was running my Data Source off of a Properties File as a resource. The reportContext().getMessage() wouldn't execute until runtime, hence the report would be unable to connect to the database to get the dynamic parameter. Hopes this helps someone!